# undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass ( Displaying Read in Crud)

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to display the contents of my database using Ruby on Rails and when I wrote this code It returns the error `"undefined method 'each' for nil:nilclass"`. Now everything I've looked at with similar issues says that that the issue lies in the controller. I've checked my controller and to be honest its very simple at the moment and its almost identical (including Case Sensitive) to one i used on a tutorial (except object names). Maybe I'm just missing something really obvious.

**VIEW**

```
<div class="item list">
 <h2>Subjects</h2>

<%= link_to("Add New item", {:action => 'new'}, :class => 'action new') %>

 <table class="listing" summary="item list">
    <tr class="header">
        <th>&nbsp;</th>
        <th>Item</th>
        <th>Visible</th>
        <th>Actions</th>
    </tr>
    <% @items.each do |item| %> 
       <tr>
        <td><%= item.position %></td>
        <td><%= item.name %></td>
        <td class="center"><%= item.visible ? 'Yes' : 'No' %></td>
        <td class="actions">
          <%= link_to ("show", {:action => 'show', :id => item.id}, :class => 'action show') %> 
          <%= link_to ("edit", {:action => 'edit', :id => item.id}, :class => 'action edit') %> 
          <%= link_to ("delete", {:action => 'delete', :id => item.id}, :class => 'action delete') %>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <% end %> 
 </table>
</div>
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
class ItemsController < ApplicationController

def list
 @items = Item.order("items.position ASC")
end 
end
```

**OTHER**

```
Processing by ItemsController#stocklist as HTML
Rendered items/stocklist.html.erb within layouts/application (7.0ms)
Completed 500 internal server error in 17ms
```

Comment: show me the development log when the page is get render, especially the "Processing by" message

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Where Would i find the development log? And my question is why isn't it working (I have a near identical copy that works. I can't see anything different.)

Comment: Are you sure that the method `list` is executed?

Comment: Oh god that was obvious after seeing it. Cheers buddy that was the issue.

Comment: It should have been 'Stocklist' not list. I've seen the issue Thank you sawa.

Comment: Btw How do I Give you rep Sawa?

Comment: @Nboaram the development log is in the console where your server run. And the "Processing by" message will let you know which controller and action is actually being call. From your log is very obvious that you are implementing the wrong action.

Comment: Dw Cenyongh i found the issue. And Yes I was. >:D

Comment: How is your view called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so for anyone in the future Sawa put me onto the issue.

In the controller It was calling list.
Now... it should have been calling "stocklist"

```
class ItemsController < ApplicationController

def stocklist
 @items = Item.order("items.position ASC")
end 
end
```

That was all that was wrong. (The little things in life make all the difference...)

Answer (score 0):

I think the the variable `@itmes` does having the array of data what you are willing to fetch.
Try debugging the and print the value inside the `@itmes` by `puts @itmes` just below your code and see if it empty and use correct condition to fetch the data like;

```
Model.all(:order => 'DATE(updated_at), price')
```